# JQuery onClick AJAX Event is Firing On Page Load instead of onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to know what in the code below is cause my onClick AJAX event to hit the server on page load and not wait for the button to be clicked on the client side. I am also open to if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do. I am using ASP.NET MVC and KendoUI controls.

Here is my view File with the code breakdown

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model GravanaWebUI.Models.Lessons.LessonPracticeViewModel

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nextQuestion").hide();
        $("#nextQuestion").removeClass("hidden");


    });


    $(document).on("click","#nextQuestion", function(e) {

        var id = @Model.ActiveLessonId;
        var url = '@Html.Action("GetNextPracticeQuestion", "Lesson")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {activeLessonId : id },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        function successFunc(data) {     
            alert(data);
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });



</script>

<style>
    .k-grid .k-header {
        display: none;
    }

    div.hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>


<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">
        <p><strong>@Model.QuestionText</strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="demo-section">

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Answers)
        .Name("answers")

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.AnswerChoiceChar).Width(10);
            columns.Bound(o => o.AnswerText).Width(200);
        })
        // .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(5))
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
        .Navigatable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            // .PageSize(5)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
         )
    )
</div>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button class="k-button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="Result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button id="nextQuestion" class="k-button hidden" >Next Question</button>
    </div>

</div>

<hr />
<script>
            function submit() {
                var grid = $('#answers').data('kendoGrid');
                var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

                if (@Model.CorrectAnswerId !== selectedItem.Id) {
                    $("#nextQuestion").hide();
                    var WrongString = "<p style='color: red'><strong>The Answer of " + selectedItem.AnswerText + " is incorrect. Please try again!</strong><p>";

                    $("#Result").html(WrongString);

                } else {
                    var rightString = "<p style='color: green'><strong>The Answer of " + selectedItem.AnswerText + " is correct. Nice Work!</strong><p>";

                    $("#Result").html(rightString);

                    $("#nextQuestion").show();
                }


            }


</script>
```

Here is the server side method that keep getting hit on load

```
public ActionResult GetNextPracticeQuestion(int activeLessonId)
{
    var viewModel = new LessonPracticeViewModel();

    return PartialView("LessonPracticeQuestionPartial", viewModel);
}
```

Any Help would be awesome thanks!

Edit

Based on the comment below here is the view that wraps the view above.

```
@model GravanaWebUI.Models.Lessons.LessonPracticeViewModel 
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Lesson - Practice"; } 
<h2>Practice</h2> 
<div id="QuestionDisplay"> @Html.Partial("LessonPracticeQuestionPartial", Model) </div> 
<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-4"> @Html.ActionLink("Next", "LessonPracticeComplete", "Lesson", new {activeLessonId = Model.ActiveLessonId}, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "k-button"} ) 
</div> </div>
```

Comment: the js code looks fine. is there any other script calling the function? maybe a partial view?

Comment: This view that is in the post is wrapped by another view as shown below 

@model GravanaWebUI.Models.Lessons.LessonPracticeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lesson - Practice";
}


<h2>Practice</h2>

<div id="QuestionDisplay">
    @Html.Partial("LessonPracticeQuestionPartial", Model)

</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ActionLink("Next", "LessonPracticeComplete", "Lesson", new {activeLessonId = Model.ActiveLessonId},
            htmlAttributes:
                new {@class = "k-button"}
            )


    </div>
</div>

Comment: please edit your question and add your code

Comment: @Sushil I have added the wrapper view

Comment: so @DerekHackett this is all there is in the view? do you have any references to script files that might have the submit function on load? also one more thing you can try is put a breakpoint in the method that is being called on load and check the call stack

Comment: @Sushil I have no references to any external scripts but the standard ones no custom files. Also I have checked the call stack and it is coming from the AJAX call in the first view file from what I can tell in VS.

Comment: can you comment out the ajax call and see if it gets called?

Comment: @Sushil Thanks for the help I commented out the Ajax call but left everything else and found the issue! I will add the answer. Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: you're most welcome @DerekHackett. m glad you figured out the issue urself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the help of comments on the question I found the issue by commenting out the code and discoverd a flaw in the usage of the HTML helper.

I had

```
@Html.Action("GetNextPracticeQuestion", "Lesson");
```

as the way of getting the URL for the Ajax call but I should have been using

```
@Url.Action("GetNextPracticeQuestion", "Lesson");
```

The action call was making the call not the AJAX call. What was surprising was the server side method had a paramiter and it was populated with the Action call above. I figured you would have to specify that or it would not find the method anyway but must be something in the ASP.NET pipes and plumping.

Thanks so much to @Sushil for the help in getting here.